# SwiftUI - How to focus a TextField within a sheet as it is appearing?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a search `TextField` within a View that is triggered to appear within a sheet on top of the `ContentView`.

I'm able to automatically focus this `TextField` when the sheet appears using `@FocusState` and `onAppear`, however, I'm finding that the sheet needs to fully appear before the `TextField` is focused and the on screen keyboard appears.

This feels quite slow and I've noticed in many other apps that they are able to trigger the on screen keyboard and the sheet appearing simultaneously.

Here is my code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showSearch = false

    var body: some View {
        Button {
            showSearch = true
        } label: {
            Text("Search")
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSearch) {
            SearchView()
        }
    }
}


struct SearchView: View {
    @State var searchTerm = ""
    @FocusState private var searchFocus: Bool

    var body: some View {
        TextField("Search", text: $searchTerm)
            .focused($searchFocus)
            .onAppear() {
                searchFocus = true
            }
    }
}
```

Is there a different way to do this that will make the keyboard appear as the sheet is appearing, making the overall experience feel more seamless?

Comment: What happens, if you give the initial value of `true` to `searchFocus`?

Comment: From what I can see, it's not possible to give an initial value to a `FocusState`?

Comment: sorry for my (deleted) answer missing the topic. Should read the question more carefully... As for your real question: I don't think this is possible with SwiftUI using `.sheet`. There might be a way building a custom sheet.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach with a custom sheet that brings in the keyboard somewhat earlier. Not sure if its worth the effort though:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showSearch = false

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Button {
                withAnimation {
                    showSearch = true
                }
            } label: {
                Text("Search")
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            
            if showSearch {
                SearchView(isPresented: $showSearch)
                    .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
            }
        }
//        .sheet(isPresented: $showSearch) {
//            SearchView()
//        }
    }
}


struct SearchView: View {
    
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    @State var searchTerm = ""
    @FocusState private var searchFocus: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            TextField("Search", text: $searchTerm)
                .focused($searchFocus)
            
            Button("Close") {
                searchFocus = false
                withAnimation {
                    isPresented = false
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear() {
            searchFocus = true
        }
    }
}
```